# how update wsdl soap which is being consumed by more than 100 clients

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I have SOAP service which is deployed on a server , which has two Operation

1 ) **Send_Message**

2 ) **Recieve_Message**

and now i want to add new Operation i.e **Send_Message_Report**

the question is what will be affect on my clients that are consuming my Wsdl ,
do they need to Re-import WSDL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure again the project calling your web service to make the web reference become updated because i know the project calling of that webservice has only two function working then you've said that you have to add another one to become three functions. Just update the reference on it so that your project has three functions and become updated.

Comment: but those clients that are not using my Third Operation , and some of will use all three then what will happen , those who do not to use will have re-import the WSDL or not . and of course those are using they will have to re-import.

Comment: all clients must update their web service reference to get the third functions. if you deployed hundreds of them then this must be a problem..